# Convert container bound google apps script to standalone

Tags: google-apps-script

About a year ago, I created a container-bound script that attaches to a spreadsheet (used to schedule users) and monitors it for changes, updating google calendars with the various events put in the spreadsheet. I created it as a container-bound script as initially this met my needs prior to publishing (I could refer to ActiveSpreadsheet, etc).

When the script was useful enough, I published it to the Sheets add-on store for others to use as well, and it now has many users - unfortunately, there are several restrictions on published container bound scripts, such as not being able to use the REST api.

I've tested the script as a standalone script using the 'test as add-on' feature, and the referents which documentation implies will not be useable as a standalone script (such as getActiveSpreadsheet) work just fine. Given this, it seems like all published scripts should be standalone. I'd like to convert mine without just making a new project and forcing all my users to uninstall the current one and install the new. Is such a conversion possible?

Comment: No, you can not change the file for the published Add-on.  If you want to change to a stand-alone, I would publish a second Add-on, but leave the first one still published.  Then give people lots of time to transition, like 6 months.  If anyone installs the old Add-on, you should inform them that they should install the new one.  Then after 6 months unpublish the old Add-on.  I see that you are new to StackOverflow, so you may not know what is considered a good and "on topic" question.  This question does not have any code, and it's really about general usage of an Add-on, which isn't really

Comment: a "good" Stack Overflow question.  You should join the [Add-on Community](https://plus.google.com/communities/117193953428311185494)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I appreciate the answer nonetheless, and will keep future questions more specific to coding issues